# id not being passed to filechooser

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd, filechooser

I have attached an image showing that the correct filechooser path is being printed out to the console when selecting the file. From that, I assume that the problem is that the **self.ids.image.source = filename[0]** is failing. Specifically, the id referencing the Image.source. I have tried changing the id and referencing the new one. That doesn't work. I'm still learning Kivy, so I'm not sure if I messed up the hierarchy and I should be calling another id to reference the filechooser's.

Also, I deleted two MDBottomNavigationItems and the contents of the other screens to clean up the code. The question is referring to the LibraryWindow screen.

**py file**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout


# Screens
class LibraryWindow(Screen):
    pass
class PlayingWindow(Screen):
    pass
class VisualWindow(Screen):
    pass

# Top Action Bar
class TopBar(BoxLayout):
    pass

# App
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "BlueGray"
        return Builder.load_file('Z:\\PycharmProjects\\kivyMD\\venv\\my.kv')

    def selected(self, filename):
        try:
            print(filename[0])
            self.ids.image.source = filename[0]
        except:
            pass

MainApp().run()
```

**Kv outline**

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TopBar:

    MDBottomNavigation:
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'navlib'
            text: "Library"
            icon: 'book'

            LibraryWindow:

#############################
### S  C  R  E  E  N  S  ###
#############################
<LibraryWindow>:
    name: "library"
    size: root.width, root.height
    id: my_widget

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5,0,0,1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        padding: 50
        spacing: 20

        Image:
            id: image
            source: ''

        FileChooserIconView:
            id: filechooser
            color: 1,.3, .3, 1

            on_selection: app.selected(filechooser.selection)

<PlayingWindow>:
<VisualWindow>:
<TopBar>:
```

Comment: I've found that changing my filechooser on_selection event to the code below fixes my issue but now I can't catch the error from going up a level in the directory. I'm not sure what the correct path from the python file to my id is. print(self.root.is) and print(self.root) are returning [BoxLayout] and "empty" (respectively).
my_widget.ids.image.source = str(filechooser.selection[0])

Comment: The `ids` that are defined in `kv` will appear in the `ids` dictionary of the object that is the root of the rule where the `id` is defined. So your `image` and `filechooser` `ids` only appear in the `ids` of the `LibraryWindow` object.

Comment: @JohnAnderson  I understand that. It seems that my first level is the BoxLayout and after that the LibraryWindow. I've tried assigning an id to the BoxLayout so that I can step down but the next list of ids does not show the LibraryWindow's id. 

I've modified my code so that I can continue working without this but going forward not being able to address my ids is definitely an issue. Do you think that you could type an example of how to access the LibraryWindow from python? I'm missing something here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Setting an `id` on the widget that is the root of a rule will not work. The `ids` are only assigned for children of the widget that is the root of the rule.

Note that the [kivy lang documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html) confuses the term `root widget`, using that term for both the root widget of the app and the root widget of a rule. The `ids` are only set in the `ids` dictionary of the widget that is the root of the rule where the `id` appears.

So, you can access the `Image` widget by adding an `id` to the `LibraryWindow` instance in the `BoxLayout` (the one that is the root of the app) like this:

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    TopBar:

    MDBottomNavigation:
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: 'navlib'
            text: "Library"
            icon: 'book'

            LibraryWindow:
                id: library
```

Then you code to set the `Image` source can become:

```
self.root.ids.library.ids.image.source = filename[0]
```

The `self.root` gets the root widget of the app. The `ids.library` gets the `LibraryWindow` instance. The `ids.image` gets the `Image` instance that has the `image` `id`.